# Facebook Comment Moderation Not Working

Tags: facebook, wordpress

I am using Facebook official plugin for WordPress for Facebook Comments. Comment plugin is working fine on the website, but its not displaying in Facebook Comment Tool (on Facebook).

[image]

Also I am not able to moderate any comment or change any settings.

[image]

I have tried using different plugins. Its not working with any of the plugin. Also I have implementing direct code for FB Comments, its also not working.

Apart from this I tried creating new Application and using it with different plugins, this method also failed.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/facebook/

Comment: I am using this plugin only. Sadly its not been updated since March 2014.

Comment: have you added the fb:admins or fb:app_id meta tag to your plugin? That is probably the problem. The setup is defined here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments#moderation-setup